# Return final observable from nested block

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, observable

Hi guys I have the following code:

```
return this.facebook.getFacebookUserInfos(req.token).pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
            return this._repo.findBy({email: user.email}).pipe(
              switchMap(foundUser => {
                // assume foundUser is always null 
                if (!foundUser) {
                  const fromFacebook = this.createUserModel(user, event.queryStringParameters);
                 return this._repo.save(fromFacebook);
                }
                return of(foundUser);
              }));
          }),
          switchMap(user => {
            return this.getAuthToken(user)
          }),
          map(response => Response.ok(response.body, response.headers)),
          catchError((err) => of(Response.errorResponse(err)))
        );
```

I'm stuck as it calls this._repo.save(fromFacebook) and doesn't wait for the observable to finish and goes to the next switch map with another observable. How can I force the block to wait for the result of this._repo.save(fromFacebook) before passing to the next one? the save method returns an observable as well. Thanks in advance for your help. 
Cheers

Comment: Just as an aside, there's no need to nest your innermost `switchMap`. If you structure the operator as: `switchMap(user => this._repo.findBy(...))`, you can slot the inner `switchMap` right after at the same level.

Comment: @miqh I originally had that, but if the return of the findBy is null, then I won't be able to create an user, since the user variable would be out of scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code snippet.

```
return this.facebook.getFacebookUserInfos(req.token).pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
            return this._repo.findBy({email: user.email}).pipe(
              switchMap(foundUser => {
                // assume foundUser is always null 
                if (!foundUser) {
                  const fromFacebook = this.createUserModel(user, event.queryStringParameters);
                 return this._repo.save(fromFacebook);
                } else {                
                 return of(foundUser);
                }
              }));
          }),
          concatMap(user => {
            return this.getAuthToken(user)
          }),
          map(response => Response.ok(response.body, response.headers)),
          catchError((err) => of(Response.errorResponse(err)))
        );
```